# «Не оправданы» или «неоправданы»

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, краткое-прилагательное, краткое-причастие

Как правильно?

> Эти расходы были не оправданы / неоправданы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Всегда нужно исходить из контекста. Если это краткое причастие или краткое прилагательное с дополнением (см. [**оправданный**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)), то пишем раздельно и с одной Н.

**Примеры:**
*Благодеяния, о которых здесь говорилось, на мой взгляд, убийственны и **не оправданы никакой государственной надобностью***.
*Мы успокоили Ивицу, что эти слухи **ничем не оправданы***.
*Я не верю чувствам: они не заслуживают слов, **пока не оправданы чем-то высшим***.

Рассматриваемое предложение я напишу только так (краткое прилагательное с двумя Н):
*Эти расходы были неоправда**нн**ы*.

[**Словари**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ладн, плюс ставлю.

Comment: @Максим Спасибо, Максим! Так что насчёт того ответа? Скажите прямо, ведь вы сами просили спрашивающих говорить, что не так с ответом и почему не приняли.

Comment: Уже не так прошу. Профиль поменял.

Comment: @Максим Теперь я прошу :)  Скажите просто: неубедительно, мало информации, не верю. Хотя если Грамота пишет, что написание не устаканено, то так и есть, и писать можно как привыкли, как принято, например, в конкретной школе, как пишет большинство, насколько частотны те или другие варианты...

Comment: «Грамота» не всегда может правду говорить — вот, в чëм дело. :) Ей можно где-то доверять, но не везде. :)

Comment: @Максим Попробуйте найти другую информацию, и тогда дадите ответ на свой вопрос. А Грамота постоянно обновляет свои материалы. Если бы написание кодифицировалось, это уже было бы в справочниках, и у неё в том числе.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%2C%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%2C%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%2C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&smoothing=6

Comment: Поскольку даже Ngram Viewer с вами согласен, я принимаю ответ.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Я соглашусь** с мнением @Александра, верна только одна форма:

*Эти расходы были **неоправданны*** (были напрасны).

2. А как же причастие: *Эти расходы **не были оправданы.***

**Вопрос № 236270.** В заголовке статьи **"Затраты не оправданы"**, как пишется НЕ?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Верно слитно: **неоправданны** (с двумя Н).

Answer (score 1):

***Эти расходы были не оправданы.***

*Оправданы* — краткое причастие. Краткие причастия всегда пишутся с НЕ раздельно.

Comment: Мне кажется очень, что здесь это более отглагольное прилагательное.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Это не отглагольное прилагательное. У отглагольныэ прилагательных нет приставок. А здесь приставка О-, влияющаа на вид глагола.