С каких букв (прописных, строчных) пишутся названия шахматных дебютов?
Примеры: (К, к)аталонское начало; (Ф, ф)ерзевый гамбит; (Д, д)ебют Гроба; (П, п)ольская защита; (З, з)ащита Тарраша; (К, к)онтратака Тракслера; (К, к)онтргамбит Альбина; (Д, д)войной (Д, д)ебют Гроба.
Также интересна первая буква в слове вариант: (В, в)ариант Алапина.


В большинстве случаев все названия используются как нарицательные существительные (строчная буква), а с прописной буквы пишутся входящие имена собственные: каталонское начало; ферзевый гамбит; дебют Гроба; польская защита; защита Тарраша; контратака Тракслера; контргамбит Альбина; двойной дебют Гроба; вариант Алапина.

Пример: каталонское начало (дебют)
Дебют получил своё название благодаря турниру 1929 года в 
Барселоне, Испания (Каталония), где был применён С. 
Тартаковером. Изначально теория относила данный дебют к 
ферзевому гамбиту, однако со временем он сформировался в 
самостоятельную систему развития[1], включающую в себя 
элементы ферзевого гамбита и дебюта Рети. Наименование этого 
дебюта родилось весьма своеобразно. На турнире в Барселоне в 
1929г. организаторы объявили конкурс, какому из еще не 
названных дебютов присвоить имя родной Каталонии. 

Пример употребления в тексте: В рамках данной статьи мы с вами сделаем обзор основных систем каталонского начала.

В то же время каждое из названий может считаться именем собственным, и тогда первое слово пишется с прописной буквы (обычно в специальной литературе).

Пример употребления в тексте: Ранее мы приводили 5 причин, почему стоит играть Каталонское начало.

Спасибо! А как определить, когда собственное?

Наверное, это выбор автора, причем чаще в специальной литературе. Вот предложение:  Могут ли белые сыграть фианкетто против других расстановок чёрных в Каталонском начале?  Здесь нормально смотрится прописная буква для падежной формы.  https://xchess.ru/katalonskoe-nachalo-polnoe-rukovodstvo.html  На конкретном ресурсе  нужно использовать одну форму (нариц. или собств.).

Ранее мы приводили 5 причин, почему стоит играть Каталонское начало. - мне кажется, тут нужны кавычки, либо нужно писать со строчной, большая буква не оправдана.

Вообще, дебют, не означает, что там прям Дебют, дебют это ряд начальных ходов с огромным числом дальнейших развитий, называть каждое развитие - это слишком усложнять. Поэтому вводят общее название для ряда похожих начал, раз оно общее, то в русском языке такие слова и выражения пишутся с маленькой буквы.

В английском же, это general nouns и их принято писать с заглавной буквы. Так что это ошибки транслита мозга.

Нет, не транслит мозга)) В русском правописании свои правила игры, а вы думаете, что их можно нарушить? Сраним с клубникой. Есть официально название - Клубника Виктория. Сорт клубники Виктория – это разновидность крупноплодной садовой земляники с высокими показателями урожайности.  В  других текстах ее могут заключить в кавычки: клубника "виктория". Если название становится общеупотребительным, то пишут как нарицательное слово.  В шахматах то же самое.

Я, кстати, теперь (с сегодняшнего дня) разбираюсь в терминах))  Может, мне в шахматисты пойти?)) Дебют (фр. début — начало) — начальная стадия шахматной партии, характеризуется мобилизацией сил играющих.
Открытый дебют является одним из наиболее распространенных дебютов в шахматах и может привести к множеству различных позиций на доске.
ВАРИАНТ — серия ходов в шахматах, которые логически связаны друг с другом.
Ферзевый гамбит - один из самых часто разыгрываемых дебютов, которым активно пользуются как совсем «зеленые» шахматисты, так и опытные гроссмейстеры мирового уровня.

Именно в открытых дебютах чаще всего можно столкнуться с гамбитами. Слово «гамбит» происходит от итальянского dare il gambetto — подставить подножку.   http://chessdeti.ru/articles/slovar.html

Кстати, об орфографии https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476093/Не-оправданы-или-неоправданы  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/479995/Газетный-спор-о-насущном  Такие бои, что там шахматы!  Трое против одного, один начинает и выигрывает. А вы пишете: Большая буква НЕ оправдаНа.

Да, я уже думаю, не начать ли мне играть в шахматы)) Теория такая интересная.   А вы, кажется, увлекаетесь шахматами? Как успехи?

Мне кажется, что шахматы – это как раз ваша игра. Почему бы вам не стать чемпионом мира)   Так что успехов вам!
